# How to run functions synchronously?

Tags: swift

I have 2 functions:

```
var path = [Int]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
    path.append(selectedRow)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var secondController: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
    println(path)

}
```

So, when I select the row it at first prints am empty array([]) for me, and just later it print which row I selected. How can I put selected row index to an array and print it?

Comment: You don't have to call `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()` since it's already passed in parameters (`indexPath`)

Comment: @Crazyrems The problem is not that he's using `indexPathForSelectedRow` rather than looking it up using `sender`. The problem is that `prepareForSegue` is called _before_ `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. If he used existing code, but used `sender` instead of `indexPathForSelectedRow`, he'd still have the same problem he has now. The problem is the order that these are called, not the mechanism that he used to identify the selected row.

Comment: @Rob Sure. Just an advice. My comment wasn't intended to answer the question.

Comment: @Crazyrems Very good. I only reacted the way I did because if you go down that road, it's a lot more work to fix the underlying problem. But you're absolutely correct that he can do that if he wants.

Answer (score 0):

They are run synchronously, just not in the order you want.

In order to take control of the order in which they are run, don't attach your segue to the cell. Instead, attach the segue to your view controller and name it with an identifier.

Then in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath, invoke your segue manually using `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:'

Comment: I used it with identifier, but it crashes with "has no segue with identifier 'body''". I did try with: `path.append(selectedRow)
        if path.count != 0 {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("body", sender: tableView)
        }` and `if segue.identifier == "body" {
            var secondController: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
            println(path)
            //secondController.rowIndex.text = "\(path[0])"
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You apparently have implemented `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` as well as hooked up a segue from the cell. The problem is that both are firing off, but the segue is being initiated before the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called.

I would suggest removing the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` entirely, and instead move the `indexPathForSelectedRow` logic into the `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: If you trigger the segue on a cell selection, that cell is passed in `sender`, so there's always a way to get your indexPath with `-tableView.indexPathForCell(UITableViewCell) -> NSIndexPath?`

Comment: Sure, if you want to do all of this programmatically you can remove the segue from the cell, implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, hook up and write `IBAction`, and have that use `sender` to determine the `cell` and then programmatically transition to the next scene (e.g. `performSegueWithIdentifier` or `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`). But that's more work than it's worth, IMHO. The OP is already using `indexPathForSelectedRow`, which works perfectly well in `prepareForSegue` and `sender` is not needed, and I think that's easier. But both techniques work.

Comment: I used it with identifier, but it crashes with "has no segue with identifier 'body''". I did try with: `path.append(selectedRow) if path.count != 0 { self.performSegueWithIdentifier("body", sender: tableView) }` and `if segue.identifier == "body" { var secondController: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController println(path) //secondController.rowIndex.text = "\(path[0])" }`.

Comment: I'm unclear why you want to go through all of that additional work, but if you want to, you have to (a) remove the existing segue between the cell and the destination; (b) add a segue between the view controllers; and (c) supply a storyboard id for that segue (tho, IMHO, using "body" seems like a poor name; perhaps something that indicates the nature of the destination). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27697632/1271826

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the segue connecting the Table Cell to the second view controller
2. Create another segue connecting the view controller to the 2nd one, giving it an identifier name (e.g. "mySegue")
3. Add a performSegueWithIdentifier call to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Here's the code:

```
  var path = [Int]()

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
    path.append(selectedRow)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: self)

  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "mySegue") {
      var secondController: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
      println(path)
    }

  }
```