# Passing value to another ViewController upon selecting cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uicollectionview, segue

I want to select a username from a UICollectionView, and pass that string to another view.

I can select the cell using "didSelectRowAtIndexPath". However the prepareForSegue function runs before my selection is set, and the segue passes the initial value.

I can't figure out how to get the index value in the prepareForSegue overide. If it were a UITableView, I think I could use indexPathForSelectedRow.

Here's what I have:

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedUsername = userNames[indexPath.row]
    selectedRow = indexPath.row

    println ("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "userSelectSegue") {

      let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController;
      nextVC.passedUsername = userNames[selectedRow]

      println("prepareForSegue")

    }
  }
```

Running this always passes userNames[0]
The output window Prints:

```
prepareForSegue
Cell 2 selected
```

EDIT 1:
I basically think I want the following tableview code, but I can't get it working for UICollectionView (i.e. I can't get the cell number):

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "userSelectSegue") {

      let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController;           
      let indexPath = UserSelectCollection.indexPathForSelectedRow()
      nextVC.passedUsername = userNames[indexPath.row]

    }
  }
```

Comment: where do you call `prepareForSegue` first ?

Comment: The same question for table views was asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538933/how-to-run-functions-synchronously.

Comment: @Spacedust_ I connected a storyboard segue from the collection cell to the other view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's How I solved it:

1. I deleted the segue connecting the collection cell to the second view controller
2. I created another segue between the two view controllers (called the identifier  "userSelectSegue")
3. Added a performSegueWithIdentifier call to the didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Here's the code:

```
  var userNames = ["Bob", "Sally", "Mike", "Mary", "James"]
  var selectedRow = 0

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedRow = indexPath.row

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("userSelectSegue", sender: self)

  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "userSelectSegue") {

      let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController;
      nextVC.passedUsername = userNames[selectedRow]
    }
  }
```

Comment: This works but you don't need to create a `selectedRow` property. Use the `performSegueWithIdentifier`'s `sender` parameter to pass your `indexPath`. See my updated answer for more details. I also provide an answer if your segue is a link between your `cell` and your `NextViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the general behavior of the iOS. What i implement is in this case is. Do not override the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. When you tap on any cell, then in the function `prepareForSegue`. You can get the cell in the sender object. From that cell get the selected item. Get the `indexPath.item`. After that get the object from the array and pass it to the next view controller.