# Force AFNetwork POST request to be synchronous

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, afnetworking

I have a button that connects a view controller to another via a segue and when pressed, sends the `text` from a `UITextField` as a parameter to an `AFNetwork` `POST` request and must decide whether the segue can continue or not depending on whether the request was successful or not.

So I wrote this:

```
var proceed = false

let token = tokenTextField.text.trim()
let requestURL = "https://myapi.com/authenticate/"

// Make this a synchronous HTTP POST request so that we only decide whether
// to proceed with the segue or not once we know if the request was successful
manager.POST(requestURL,
    parameters: [ "code" : token ],
    success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
        proceed = true

        NSLog("Success! Response is \(responseObject.description)")
    },
    failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
        println("Failure! Error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")

        proceed = false

        self.displayLoginAttempErrorAlert()
}).waitUntilFinished()

println("what a hard thing")
return proceed
```

But this code prints `"what a hard thing"` before anything printed within the `success` or `error` callbacks, so it is obviously asynchronous. For the reasons explained above, I want it to be synchronous. How can I force that behavior?

Please bear in mind that there is nothing wrong with the request itself. I just wanna ensure the right order of things.

**UPDATE**: I'm aware that forcing things to be synchronous may block the UI and that's fine for my purpose. This is like a login screen where nothing should really happen between the issuing of the request and the arrival of the response.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like it would be better to have the HTTP request's completion blocks call methods which would then decide the behaviour to take, rather than relying on the return code of that method. For example, the `success` block could call a method which would then push the next view controller (or whatever action has to be taken for the user to proceed), and the `failure` block could display the login error. Forcing a network request to be synchronous will block the UI while the request takes place, which isn't a great user experience.

Comment: Thanks for the input but this screen may be blocked fine and nothing should happen between performing the request and receiving the response from the server. Besides, everything happens within `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` which must return a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

- specify the `completionQueue` of the `manager` to be something other than the main queue (so that you don't deadlock when you block the main thread, waiting for the completion handler to be called);
- `dispatch_semaphore_semaphore` before you start the request;
- `dispatch_semaphore_signal` the semaphore inside the completion block of the request; and
- `dispatch_semaphore_wait` for the semaphore after the request, but before you return from your function.

But making an asynchronous method behave synchronously is fundamentally the incorrect approach, in my opinion. Not only is it a poor UX, limits your UI, etc., but also you risk having the watchdog process kill your app.

Rather than making an asynchronous process behave synchronously in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`, I would instead employ a standard asynchronous pattern:

- remove the existing segue you presumably have from the UIKit control to the next scene;
- create a new segue between the view controllers (as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27697632/1271826)) that won't be performed automatically, but only programmatically (see below);
- have an `IBAction` that performs the asynchronous request, and have a completion block that
- initiates the segue programmatically, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you call your `viewController` in success block... we also have the same situation where user has a login screen and while authentication if failure occurs then we need to show alert else on success redirect it to `homeViewController`.

If you use `queueCompletion` block it will be same as handling it in success block if you are executing only one operation in queue.

Still needs a synchronous call then use NSURLConnection class of iOS

```
-[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error]
```